# Vee validate validating rows without v-model

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I'm having a problem with vee-validate and validation inside v-for & when v-model is not provided but instead we have @input & value

Here is my CodeSandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-williamson-8nkou

What I'm trying to produce is to validate every new row that is added to the list, when user types something into the TextArea, I want to be validated ?

Comment: Try to include the relevant code in your question!  Links are great but if for some reason it stops working, it's best to have the whole question right on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On input, use ValidationProvider's scoped slot prop [validate](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/api/validation-provider.html#scoped-slot-props).  Here's a general example:

```
<ValidationProvider v-slot="{ validate }" rules="required">
    <input :value="myValue" @input="validate($event)" name="foo"/>
</ValidationProvider>
```